# Get columns in frame based on values in second frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes. One has a ID column with alot of arranged IDs.
The other one has just specific rows of the first column. Those are my markers.
I need to get the sum of the of the values in a specific column based on the id values of the second column.
The first column may be

```
id   goals   cards   group
1      2       2       1
2      3       2       1
3      4       2       1
4      5       1       1      
5      1       2       1
1      2       2       2
2      3       2       2
3      4       2       2
4      5       1       3      
5      1       2       3
```

the second one:

```
 id   goals   cards   group
  2      3       2      1
  5      1       2      1
  2      3       2      2
  3      4       2      2
  5      1       2      3
```

what  i need to get:

```
 id   goals   cards   group   points
 1      2       2       1      2-(2+2)
 2      3       2       1      0 cause in second list
 3      4       2       1      4-(2+1+2)
 4      5       1       1      5-(1+2)
 5      1       2       1      0 cause in second list
 1      2       2       2      2-(2+2)
 2      3       2       2      0
 3      4       2       2      0
 4      5       1       3      5-(1+2)  
 5      1       2       3      0
```

Something like: ??

```
df1<- df1%>%
rowwise() %>% 
mutate(points= 
       goals
       -(sum( df1$cards[df1$id <= df2$id & df1$id>df1$id])))
```

Comment: No idea what's happening here. Can you explain a bit more of how you calculate the points in each row? Also, at some point you start referring to your datasets as columns. You forgot to close your `]` within mutate. Try to remove `df1$` within `mutate` and just use your variables. Eg. `cards` instead of `df1$cards`, `id` instead of `df1$id`.

Comment: This code sample is just random typed. I tried a few things but it did not work. The only important part is the sum part. so i want to sum  the values in my cards column in a specific range based on my second data frame. the rows which are used to sum are those where the id is smaller|equal to the first id of the second data frame where the id is bigger then all previous ids but smaller|equal then the used one.

Comment: goals do not matter at all. its just a value where i have to subtract the sum the column "cards" from the dataframe1 which is filtered based on conditions. Those conditions are: the ids have to be smaller then the first bigger ID-value in the dataframe2 and bigger then the all previous IDs in dataframe2 and bigger then themself. so dataframe1$id < dataframe2$id(first id, which is bigger[list is arranged] & dataframe1$id > dataframe2$id(all previous ones - maybe not neccessary?) & dataframe$1 > dataframeq$id(the current rows id

Comment: I think I got the pattern you want to apply. Check my answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
id   goals   cards
1      2       2
2      3       2
3      4       2
4      5       1
5      1       2
", header=T)

df2 = read.table(text = "
id   goals   cards  
2      3       2
5      1       2
", header=T)

library(dplyr)

# function that gets an id and returns the sum of cards based on df2
GetSumOfCards = function(x) {
  ids = min(df2$id[df2$id >= x])                        # for a given id of df1 find the minimum id in df2 that is bigger than this id 
  ifelse(x %in% df2$id,                                 # if the given id exists in df2
         0,                                             # sum of cards is zero
         sum(df1$cards[df1$id >= x & df1$id <= ids]))   # otherwise get sum of cards in df1 from this id until the id obtained before                  
}

# update function to be vectorised
GetSumOfCards = Vectorize(GetSumOfCards)


df1 %>%
  mutate(sum_cards = GetSumOfCards(id),      # get sum of cards for each id using the function
         points = goals - sum_cards)         # get the points

#   id goals cards sum_cards points
# 1  1     2     2         4     -2
# 2  2     3     2         0      3
# 3  3     4     2         5     -1
# 4  4     5     1         3      2
# 5  5     1     2         0      1
```

Based on your updated question, applying a similar function to every row makes the process very slow. So, this solution groups data in a way that you can just count the cards on chunks of data/rows:

```
df1 = read.table(text = "
id   goals   cards   group
                 1      2       2       1
                 2      3       2       1
                 3      4       2       1
                 4      5       1       1      
                 5      1       2       1
                 1      2       2       2
                 2      3       2       2
                 3      4       2       2
                 4      5       1       3      
                 5      1       2       3
                 ", header=T)

df2 = read.table(text = "
                 id   goals   cards   group
                 2      3       2      1
                 5      1       2      1
                 2      3       2      2
                 3      4       2      2
                 5      1       2      3
                 ", header=T)

library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  arrange(group, desc(id)) %>%                                  # order by group and id descending (this will help with counting the cards)
  left_join(df2 %>%                                             # join specific columns of df2 and add a flag to know that this row exists in df2
              select(id, group) %>%
              mutate(flag = 1), by=c("id","group")) %>%
  mutate(flag = ifelse(is.na(flag), 0, flag),                   # replace NA with 0
         flag2 = cumsum(flag)) %>%                              # this flag will create the groups we need to count cards 
  group_by(group, flag2) %>%                                    # for each new group (we need both as the card counting will change when we have a row from df2, or if group changes)
  mutate(sum_cards = ifelse(flag == 1, 0, cumsum(cards))) %>%   # get cummulative sum of cards unless the flag = 1, where we need 0 cards
  ungroup() %>%                                                 # forget the grouping
  arrange(group, id) %>%                                        # back to original order
  mutate(points = goals - sum_cards) %>%                        # calculate points
  select(-flag, -flag2)                                         # remove flags

# # A tibble: 10 x 6
#      id goals cards group sum_cards points
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1     2     2     1         4     -2
# 2     2     3     2     1         0      3
# 3     3     4     2     1         5     -1
# 4     4     5     1     1         3      2
# 5     5     1     2     1         0      1
# 6     1     2     2     2         4     -2
# 7     2     3     2     2         0      3
# 8     3     4     2     2         0      4
# 9     4     5     1     3         3      2
# 10    5     1     2     3         0      1
```

Comment: So there is no NA value and yes df1 has groups which do not exist in df2 since i trimmed my data randomly. So there is no warning if I do not do that but it still does not finish. I have like 60000 obs in df1 and 600 in df2.

Comment: you are right. it seems that the data is to much to handle with a normal computer and this method. trimming to 2000 in df1 worked now :/

Comment: Doing it with 20 rows before the id of df2 occours in df1 could kinda solve it. It would just do this operation to df2.length * 20 rows instead of 60k. Hmm

Comment: I think the function was a trap :-) I used a completely different method using groups of data chunks to count the cards. Have look to understand how it works and check if it works in your big dataset as well (hopefully faster).